# HTML <video> tag

Tags: javascript, html, video

When i'm play video which i have locally on my computer like this:

```html
<video id="player">
 <source src="/videobox/videos/Mamacita.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

everything works fine.
But when i'm trying to play video from another site like youtube, i'm using absolute url path like this:

```js
<video id="player">
 <source src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ob3ktDxAjWI" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

it is not work, how i can play videos not from my computer?

Comment: That's not how youtube videos work. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: you need the URL of the actual video file. In you case you are trying to use the URL of a webpage (youtube.com)

Comment: Okay, but i tried not only from youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Your YouTube link is not to an MP4 file (or any other video format). It's to a YouTube player that then calls the source video itself.

When embedding a video like this make sure your source is indeed the source. If it doesn't end in ".mp4", ".avi" etc... then it's probably not the source you want.

If you want to embed a YouTube video use this HTML code:

```
<iframe width="X" height="Y" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ob3ktDxAjWI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Alternatively you can download the video file from YouTube and host it locally but only do that if it's your video or you have the express permission of whoever's video it is.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add video from Youtube using `<video>` tag. In order to do it you should use `<iframe>`. Your code should look like this:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ob3ktDxAjWI?autoplay=1"
  frameborder="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

YouTube videos have very specific ways they allow themselves to be embedded, and the way you are attempting it here is not correct. The embed code you have there **does not** return a raw `.mp4` file, it returns actual HTML structure that the video lives inside. Thus, the `<video />` tag has no idea what to do with it. Please use another video source that provides an actual video file to the `source` attribute and update your question if it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this! If you're using a video from another website you have to use the function

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ob3ktDxAjWI?autoplay=1"
frameborder="0"/>
```